# Setting PHP CLI timezone

Tags: nitrousio

I have added my timezone to `date.timezone` in `~/.parts/etc/php5/php.ini` but my PHP script that I execute on the console keep saying

```
We selected the timezone 'UTC' for now, 
but please set date.timezone to select your timezone.
```

Is there any solution for this?

**UPDATES**:

1. I found out that PHP on Apache recognize my setting in php.ini but PHP command line is not.
2. Somehow now it's working. I accept @carousel answer because I think it is informative for others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with:

```
date_default_timezone_set
```

method, which is used by all date/time functions.

UPDATE:

With PHP date/time settings you have to be very explicit, and don't rely on some predefined settings.

Comment: Hmm. I dont get it. Where should I put the method?

Comment: In some global place, relative to your application.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. So in Nitrous I can't set the value from `php.ini` then?

Comment: Basic principle is to control your settings as much as you can. If you server environment is reliable then use it. But environment can change. You can modify PHP settings on different levels.

Comment: Glad to help. Please accept answer if you find it useful.

Comment: `date_default_timezone_set` did not work in the script I'm calling from CLI; I'm not sure why yet.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the -c option when using php cli to specify a php.ini file to use.

For my Nitrous box, I use:

```
php -c /home/action/.parts/etc/php5/php.ini yourcommandshere
```